# Apache2 authorization with database and authentication with certificate

Tags: apache-2.4

My users have a certificate and can get access to my Apache 2.4 server, that's fine.

They have access with their certificates to the whole site.
But I want only certain users grant access to '/private'. How can I configure this.
My first try:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "dbname=xxx user=xxx pass=xxx"

DBDMin  4
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax  20
DBDExptime 300

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ankara.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ankara.key
ServerName ankara.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/ankara 
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 5
SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ca.crt"
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +FakeBasicAuth

SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}e"


<Location "/private">
AuthName "Private"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider dbd

AuthDBDUserPWQuery \
    "SELECT   %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} "
Require dbd-group team
AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT group FROM group WHERE naam = %s"
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The result is Internal Server error.
In the apache error log:

AH00632: failed to prepare SQL statements: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}' at line 1

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, for anyone interested:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# mod_dbd configuration
    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "dbname=xxx user=xxx pass=xxx"

    DBDMin  4
    DBDKeep 8
    DBDMax  20
    DBDExptime 300

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ankara.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ankara.key
    ServerName ankara.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ankara 
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 5
    SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ca.crt"
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

    SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN


<Location "/">
    AuthName "Private"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider dbd

    Require dbd-group team
    AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT groep FROM groep WHERE naam = %s"
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache replaces %s with SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN from the certificate.